# How to author a .spec file that requires either sl-release or centos-release or redhat-release?

Tags: centos, redhat, rpmbuild

I reckon my question is somewhat related to "https://serverfault.com/q/299179" and "https://serverfault.com/q/283330/71790", but then there was no satisfying answer there for me in either of those.

In order to ensure that the dependencies are correct for my `.rpm`, I want to require a particular minimum release. In my case `sl-release >= 6.1`. Alright, so I wrote `Requires: sl-release >= 6.1` in the `.spec` file and then it dawned on me: "What if somebody tries to install this on one of the related distros?" (like CentOS or RHEL itself).

Since Scientific Linux is based on RHEL, like CentOS, there should be a way to express that I require something based off a particular RHEL release. Alas, a quick `yum list installed|grep release` only yielded:

```
sl-release.x86_64  6.1-2         @anaconda-ScientificLinux-201107272231.x86_64/6
```

Dang, `sl-release` was clearly specific to Scientific Linux (and `yum list` wasn't any more helpful and `yum grouplist` offered nothing either). So I thought the dependency must be somehow expressed by `Provides:` and issued a `yum deplist sl-release`. Alas, the output was again not helpful to my cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... turns out that aside from the conditionals pointed out in "https://serverfault.com/q/283330/71790", there is something like a symbolic/alias name for the above. Guessing a little, a web search turned up `centos-release` and of course `redhat-release` as the package names used on the other two related distros.

Since it took me some time to come up with the solution and sharing is caring, I decided to write down what I found for the next internaut doing a web search.

So, next I ran `yum install redhat-release` in order to install it, hoping it would be available. It *was*:

```
$ sudo yum install redhat-release
Setting up Install Process
Package sl-release-6.1-2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Apparently the name `redhat-release` somehow magically translates to `sl-release`. I.e. it's an alias.

#### Conclusion

You can use the generic name `redhat-release`, even on the two derived distros CentOS and Scientific Linux to refer to the respective distribution-specific packages `centos-release` and `sl-release`. So:

```
Require: redhat-release >= 6.1
```

does the job on all of them.

---

On a related note, I knew that all of them have a file `/etc/redhat-release` and `yum whatprovides /etc/redhat-release` gave me:

```
$ yum whatprovides /etc/redhat-release
sl-release-6.1-2.x86_64 : Scientific Linux release file
Repo        : local
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/redhat-release



sl-release-6.1-2.x86_64 : Scientific Linux release file
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: /etc/redhat-release
```

Comment: `slf-release` is another common variant.